# How to get star ratings on google places

Tags: php, r

I need to get the google places notations back to integrate them into my website. I have several notes to retrieve. I would like to retrieve them via an R or PHP code but I don't know how to do it. Could you help me?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have already tried?

Comment: Your first step is likely to find documentation on the respective API, and "googling" for [`google places stars api`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=google+places+stars+api) is a fruitful start. From there, choose a language. While I know that both [tag:r] and [tag:php] provide general HTTP interfacing, perhaps there exists a package somewhere to automate some of the nuances of the published API. After that, give it a try! If/when you hit a roadblock, then come back to SO with some code and errors/warnings, and we can help you better then. (Now? Too broad.)

Comment: Specifically, SO specifically lists as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions that *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"*, which your question is doing. Questions appropriate for SO involve (same link) *"a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers, ... software development"*. Often (but not always), "good" (popular) questions are *reproducible*; c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.